# Monitor a application/server in real-time through its log

Tags: monitoring, real-time, logging

Is there any tool that can analyze in real-time a log (a custom server application) and output custom metrics over the log? Possibly some graphs on a web interface?

My typical use case is the following: I have a socket server receiving incoming requests. Each request is of a specific "type". I would like to see pieces of information like: how many requests occurred in the last N minutes? The average time of response for the requests (each logged request has its response time); How many requests of a single type has occurred in the last N minutes? And others.

I'm aware that specific information contained in a log item cannot be automatically extracted and I would probably need some coding to instruct the tool how to parse and understand the log, and how it could gather information out of it.

Is there a tool/software/system/monitor that could help with that?

Comment: A buddy said he loves http://www.tableausoftware.com/ for exploring his pile of data.

Answer (score 1):

Send Jabber/XMPP message to user@jabberserver.com when new line is appended to the log:

```
# tail --follow=name --retry /var/log/logfile.log | sendxmpp -i -u username -p password -j jabberserver.com user@jabberserver.com
```

username/password must be created on jabberserver.com. user@jabberserver.com must be loged in via Jabber/XMPP client that you write on your own (I prefer perl + Net::Jabber). Then you can do whatever you want with the incoming XMPP messages (store on DB, send e-mail, ...).

Answer (score 0):

[Tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) is the most common tool I know of and if your on windows there is [wintail](http://download.cnet.com/Hoo-WinTail/3000-2218_4-10425410.html).

Answer (score 0):

At Ustream we needed a tool just like that, so we wrote [Yolo](https://github.com/ustream/yolo). It is a general log parser and processor that can send data to StatsD, which aggregates the data you need (it supports counters, timing data and gauges) and sends to Graphite.

In a nutshell you just have to write a config file, setup a regexp parser to match your log data and setup the statsd keys you want to use. You don't have to write any code.

You can find an example config on Github.